# Jquery selectors: Select any words

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do i select with a selector all the words that are between two spaces? I don't want to select all the words with a complicated algorithm, i just want to apply a function when the mouse goes over a word in a div. And it is a e-book, this means, i need a efficient way to solve this..

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK textnodes are not suitable candidates for attaching events. Nor are they "selectable" by jQuery.

You can select the parent node of some text using the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and attach events to that.

### Update

What you can do is find your text's parent element and replace its inner HTML with some modified markup, eg

```
var parent = $(':contains("My Text")');
var text = parent.html();
parent.html(text.replace(/My Text/g, '<span class="hover-event">$&</span>'));

$('.hover-event').mouseenter(function(e) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer that I could come up with was to use a regex to select each word in the div and surround it with `<span>` tags that had `onmouseover` events defined.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var text = $("#wordHoverable").html().trim();
        var newText = "";
        var wordRegex = /\w*/;     //Selects 'word characters' (alpha-numeric)
        var nonWordRegex = /\W*/;  //Selects all other characters

        var foundWord = text.match(wordRegex);
        while (foundWord != "") {
          newText += "<span onmouseover=\"hoverFunc('" + foundWord + "');\">" +
                foundWord + "</span>";
          text = text.replace(wordRegex, "");
          var nonWordChars = text.match(nonWordRegex);
          newText += nonWordChars;
          text = text.replace(nonWordRegex, "");
          foundWord = text.match(wordRegex);
        }
        $("#wordHoverable").html(newText);
      });

      function hoverFunc(text) {
        //Do whatever when their mouse is over the word
        $("#currentWord").html(text);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Current word: <span id="currentWord"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="wordHoverable">
      Hi there everyone.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the same code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpvtn/1/

This may not be very efficient to run on a large scale on-the-spot, but you could use this as sort of a "compiler" to convert easy-to-read, plain text in a `<div>` and convert it to the interactive text that you want.

Like Phil said, I don't think you can actually attach events to the individual words themselves unless you wrap them in `<span>` tags.